# Mysql group post_id by max count status

Tags: mysql, sql, database

hi i have an mysql query where it will return post_id by max counts of status, The result it display currently is

```
POST_ID

    3
```

Mysql Table:

```
(`post_id`, `user_id`, `status`, `date_created`)
(2, 2, 'funny', 20121022120627)
(2, 3, 'lame', 20121023120627)
(3, 1, 'useful', 20121023120627)
(3, 3, 'lame', 20121023120627)
(3, 4, 'useful', 20121023120627)
(4, 4, 'useful', 20121024120627)
```

But the result i need is, to display the count from max to min on desc order.if 2 result having same number, then the top result will be based on the latest date_created similar like this

```
POST_ID

     3
     2
     4
```

My current query is

```
SELECT post_id
FROM tableName
GROUP BY post_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 
(
    SELECT MAX(x.counts)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) counts
        FROM tableName
        GROUP BY post_id
    ) x
)
```

The sample can be found on SQLFiddle [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a515e/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But the result i need is, to display the count from max to min on desc
>   order.if 2 result having same number, then the top result will be
>   based on the latest date_created.

You need to `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, date_created DESC` like so:

```
SELECT post_id
FROM tableName
GROUP BY post_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 
(
    SELECT MAX(x.counts)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) counts
        FROM tableName
        GROUP BY post_id
    ) x
)
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, date_created DESC
```

**UPDATE 1**

Try this,

```
SELECT post_id
FROM tableName
GROUP BY post_ID
ORDER BY  COUNT(*) DESC, MAX(`date_created`) DESC
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a515e/13)

Comment: @zlippr, It is working fine. Your sample data only has one returned row. see [**the updates fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1b5a/1)

Comment: @MahmoudGamal you will see the green magical thing there later :p

Comment: @JohnWoo - Thanks again. It should be your answer.